# BottomSheet touch area taking all the screen

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I've added a bottom sheet and to my view and it works normally but the touch area which I can drag the sheet is taking all the screen.
the view code is looking like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_image">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/color_primary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp">

        <com.oxzimo.fabric.ui.DetailsImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <include layout="@layout/item_detail" />
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_wallpaper_white_24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_set_wallpaper"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'd like to know why this behavior is there and how can I make the touch area including the bottom sheet only.

Comment: mostly because of `@layout/item_detail`. But you did not include it in your question

Comment: do you mean that include is making this behavior?

Comment: I am saying that layout you include might.